# Срабатывание popup при закрытии окна

Tags: javascript

На сайте установлен код popunder, который срабатывает, если пользователь сделает клик в любом месте сайта. Как сделать так, чтобы за клик считалось закрытие окна (сайта)?

При этом браузер не должен заблокировать новое окно.

Сразу уточню, что речь идет не о диалоговом окне типа "вы уверены что хотите покинуть сайт".

Пробовал следующий код, но не получилось:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].click();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто используйте [`onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) вместо `onbeforeunload`, а блокировку окна не обойти. Никак. И это правильно. Но если это не диалоговое окно и не окно в привычном смысле, то проблема блокировки и не встанет.

```
window.onunload = function() {
    // стафф
}
```